How to inject a hosted service when it also implements other interface
I have the following interface in my .NET Core web application:
public interface IIntegrationManagerService : IHostedService
{
    Task<List<IFunciones>> GetFunctionList();
}

The implementation is as follows:
public class IntegrationManagerService : IIntegrationManagerService, IDisposable

I am adding in Program.cs this way:
services.AddHostedService<IIntegrationManagerService>();

When doing that, an exception is thrown when services are built.
If I change the above line with this:
services.AddHostedService<IntegrationManagerService>();

Services are built, but an exception is thrown when the class where the object is to be injected is instantiated.

If I inject IHostedService no exception is thrown, but I cannot use IIntegrationManagerService methods.
How can I do it?
I tried by adding a singleton, but Start method of the service obviously is not called.

The interface inheritance works - although I don't see, why you would use it (see "I" in SOLID pronciple). You say "Start method is not called". Could it be, that you're defining more than one IHostedService? In that case, the "Start" method of the second service is not started before the Start method of first has ended. Order is the order of DI registration.

Are you trying to reference your Hosted Service from a controller? If I recall, Hosted Services are added to the DI Container with scoped lifetime. They can be pulled from the IServiceProvider if you inject it into your controller:
    var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var service = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIntegrationManagerService>();

If this doesn't work, you can configure your hosted service to be responsive to events raised within the controller. This might be considered an anti-pattern, but would provide a viable, reusable solution.
Good luck!

"..., Hosted Services are added to the DI Container with scoped lifetime" - They're not.  AddHostedService uses services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService, THostedService>());

Ah. Thanks for the correction! Singleton services can be retrieved the same way, I believe.
